# Using ServiceStack.Redis with RedisCloud

Tags: redis, servicestack

Using [RedisCloud](http://redis-cloud.com/) as a datastore for a [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) based [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) hosted app.

The RedisCloud [.net client documentation](http://redis-cloud.com/redis/developers/redis-redis-windows) states to **not** use the [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) connection managers:

> Note: the ServiceStack.Redis client connection managers (BasicRedisClientManager and PooledRedisClientManager) should be disabled when working with the Garantia Data Redis Cloud. Use the single DNS provided upon DB creation to access your Redis DB. The Garantia Data Redis Cloud distributes your dataset across multiple shards and efficiently balances the load between these shards.

Why would they suggest that? Because they are doing fancy load balancing stuff in their 'Garantia Data' layer and don't want to handle unnecessary connections? The `RedisClient` class is not thread-safe, so it makes it much more difficult from the application programming perspective.

Should I just ignore their instructions and use a `PooledRedisClientManager`? How would I configure it with the single uri that RedisCloud provides?

Or will I need to write a basic `RedisClient` pool wrapper that just creates new `RedisClient` connections as needed to handle concurrent access (i.e. ignores all read/write pooling specifics, hopefully delegating all that up-stream to the RedisCloud layer)?

Answer (score 1):

**Why would they suggest that? Because they are doing fancy load balancing stuff in their 'Garantia Data' layer and don't want to handle unnecessary connections?**
I think you could be right. To my knowledge these classes simply wrap creating/retrieving instances of `RedisClient` (though, I think Basic always creates a new RedisClient). While I looked over [their site](http://redis-cloud.com), I did't see anything about 'max number of connections to the Redis server(s). The previous Redis vendor from AppHarbor (MyRedis) had plans that listed the number of max connections allowed per plan. However, I also didn't see anything on the site mention connection limits/handling.

**Should I just ignore their instructions and use a PooledRedisClientManager? How would I configure it with the single uri that RedisCloud provides?**
Well, if you do ignore their instructions my guess is you could eventually run into a 'max number of connections exceeded' error. That would make it difficult to get to your Redis Server(s). I think you could still use the `BasicRedisClientManager` because when you call `GetClient()` it always 'news up' a RedisClient in the same way shown in their example.